# How to change background color of Custom CollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to change the background color of my custom collection view cell in the **didSelectItemAtIndexPath**.
Here is my implementation.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
    didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    RadioCollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"RadioCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setData:self.contentModel andIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lblChoice.backgroundColor = ColorFromRGB(COLOR_GREEN);
}
```

Here is my implementation for **RadioCollectionViewCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RadioCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblChoice;

    - (void)setData:(ContentModel *)contentModel andIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
    + (RadioCollectionViewCell *)loadFromNib;
@end
```

But the background color did not change. When I check the sample solutions, they are just changing the background color of `UICollectionViewCell`. Not the custom one. I just want to know that can I do that in the `CustomAnnotationView`?

Comment: Please,provide more code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = ColorFromRGB(COLOR_GREEN);
```

However, you should check how you are designing the RadioCollectionViewCell cell in storyboard itself. Because if the designer of that cell added another UIView on top of the contentView, then you need to get a reference to that view and change the background of that view instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have added a label with the equal width and height of that RadioCollectionViewCell. I tried to change the color of that label instead of cell's background color. But it did not work. I dun know why.

Comment: If you want to change color of label then u need to get the label’s iboutlet and set the color normally

Comment: Show the code how u change label color. and also post the header of your RadioCollectionViewCell.

Comment: I have updated the questions for more code. Please check.

Comment: I updated my code according to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402263/difference-between-dequeuereusablecellwithreuseidentifier-and-cellforitematinde). And it works now. I updated "cellforItemAtIndexPath" instead of using "dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier". Thanks for ur help.